# Backcolor of THE BORDER of a Windows Forms panel

Tags: winforms, panel, border

Is there any way to change the `BackColor` of the border of a panel or similar control?

I am trying to "highlight" the user control when I hover the mouse over the user control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple class that highlights controls on the form with a border:

```
    public class Highlighter : Control
    {
        public void SetTarget(Control c)
        {
            Rectangle r = c.Bounds;
            r.Inflate(3, 3);
            Bounds = r;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, e.ClipRectangle);
        }
    }
```

Then, in your form, set everything to use it:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            c.MouseEnter += mouseEnter;
            c.MouseLeave += mouseLeave;
        }
    }

    private void mouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _highlighter.SetTarget(sender as Control);
        _highlighter.Visible = true;
    }

    private void mouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _highlighter.Visible = false;
    }
```

Then, in the constructor, just create the highlighter:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _highlighter = new Highlighter();
        Controls.Add(_highlighter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MouseEnter / MouseLeave events to do this.

```
    private void panel1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: not the panel's backcolor.  i want to change the backcolor of the BORDER

Comment: You're question states "the backcolor of a panel or similar control". Re-Edit your question with correct information if you want correct answers

Comment: sorry about that . . i have removed the down tick